# hardware specification recommendation for Solr

Tags: solr, hardware

I am looking for a hardware specification for Solr search engine. Our requirement is to build a search system which indexes about 5 to 9 million documents. The peak query per second is around 50 people. I checked the Dell website and think that maybe a Rack Server is good. So I made a sample product. How do you think about my choice? Do you have any experience on hardware specification for Solr system?

PowerEdge R815
R815 Chassis for Up to Six 2.5 Inch Hard Drives

Processor

2x AMD Opteron 6276, 2.3GHz, 16C, Turbo CORE, 16M L2/16M L3, 1600Mhz Max Mem

Additional Processor

No 3rd/4th Processors   edit

Operating System

No Operating System edit

OS Media kits

None    edit

OS and SW Client Access Licenses

None    edit

Memory

64GB Memory (8x8GB), 1333MHz, Dual Ranked LV RDIMMs for 2 Processors    edit

Hard Drive Configuration

No RAID for PERC H200 Controllers (Non-Mixed Drives)    edit

Internal Controller

PERC H200 Integrated RAID Controller    edit

Hard Drives

1TB 7.2K RPM SATA 2.5in Hot-plug Hard Drive edit

Data Protection Offers

None    edit

Embedded Management

iDRAC6 Express  edit

System Documentation

Electronic System Documentation and OpenManage DVD Kit  edit

Network Adapter

Intel® Gigabit ET NIC, Dual Port, Copper, PCIe-4    edit

Network Adapter

Intel® Gigabit ET NIC, Dual Port, Copper, PCIe-4    edit

Host Bus Adapter/Converged Network Adapter

None    edit

Power Supply

1100 Watt Redundant Power Supply    edit

Power Cords

NEMA 5-15P to C13 Wall Plug, 125 Volt, 15 AMP, 10 Feet (3m), Power Cord edit

BIOS Setting

Performance BIOS Setting    edit

Rails

No Rack Rail or Cable Management Arm    edit

Bezel

PowerEdge R815 Bezel    edit

Internal Optical Drive

DVD ROM, SATA, Internal

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Marko (not myself, other Marko:).

You should use e.g. [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to test capabilities (the most important metric of course being: how response time changes with number of parallel users) of your configuration and then make educated decision based on those results.

Be prepared to play with JVM memory settings in order to see how if affects overall performance.
I'd also test various application servers to see how that decision affects response time.

PS If you choose to use jMeter you should definitely make use of [jMeter Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/), which will allow you ([Composite graph](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/CompositeGraph)) to show number of parallel users and response time with server's processor, memory and network loads on the same graph.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hugely open ended question, with far too many details unknown - the straw-man hardware spec is really not very useful (TL;DR)

There is only one sensible way to go about tackling this problem and that is empirically.